# PowerShellのGroupBox内にラベルやテキストボックスが表示されない

Tags: powershell

サブフォーム内にいくつかのグループを設けて、それらボックス内にテキストやラベルなどを作りたいです。入力フォームを作るイメージです。

今回問題となっている部分のコードは下記になります

```
# サブフォーム
$optionform = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$optionform.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$optionform.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,500)
$optionform.MaximizeBox = $False
$optionform.MinimizeBox = $false
$optionform.text = "オプション"
$optionform.Owner = $form # $formはメインフォーム

# 略：クロージングイベントやクリックイベントなど

# グループ1
$Group1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$Group1.Location = New-Object　System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$Group1.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(220,115)
$Group1.text = "グループ1"
$optionform.Controls.Add($Group1)

## グループ1：ラベル1
$Label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,20)
$Label1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(55,20)
$Label1.Text = "ラベル1"
$Group1.Controls.Add($Label1)

## 略：ほかにもテキストやコンボボックスがあります

# グループ2
$Group2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$Group2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(235,10)
$Group2.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(220,115)
$Group2.text = "グループ2"
$optionform.Controls.Add($Group2)

## グループ2：テキストボックス1
$textBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(240,20)
$textBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(55,20)
$Group2.Controls.Add($textBox1)

## 略：ほかにもテキストやコンボボックスがあります
```

これを実行するとGroup1とGroup1内に配置しているラベル類とGroup2は表示されます。しかしGroup2内に配置しているテキスト類は表示されません。

2点試したことがあります。
1つ目は、Group2内に配置予定のテキスト類をGroup1内に配置するように書き換えてGroup1のサイズを大きくしたことです。この場合は問題なく表示されました。
2つ目は、Group2自体を消して、サブフォームである$optionformに直接配置したことです。この場合も、問題なく表示されました。

以上から、Group2の配置?コードの書き方?に問題があるのではと考えているのですが、問題の箇所が見当もつかず手詰まりです。
これは何が問題なのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

New-Object System.Drawing.Point()の理解が間違っていたようです。
どのGroupBoxでも基準（Point(0,0)）は必ず左上かと思っていたのですが、ラベルやテキストの配置は、あくまで配置するGroupBoxの左上が基準のようです。
実際、ラベルやテキストなどのSystem.Drawing.Point()をもっと小さくすると表示されました。

Comment: 解決されたのであればご自身の回答を承認してください。自己解決されても何ら問題ありません。

Comment: ✔をおそうと思っても48時間はできないようで…。

Answer (score 0):

回答ではありません。が、コードを見て気になったので。

PowerShellでは[ハッシュ テーブルからオブジェクトを作成する](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_object_creation?view=powershell-7.3#create-objects-from-hash-tables)ことができます。具体的にはこんな感じ。

```
$optionform = [System.Windows.Forms.Form]@{
    StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    Size = @{ Width = 500; Height = 500; }
    MaximizeBox = $False
    MinimizeBox = $false
    Text = "オプション"
    Owner = $form # $formはメインフォーム
}

$Group1 = [System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox]@{
    Location = @{ X = 10; Y = 10; }
    Size = @{ Width = 220; Height = 115; }
    Text = "グループ1"
}
$optionform.Controls.Add($Group1)

$Group1.Controls.Add([System.Windows.Forms.Label]@{
    Location = @{ X = 15; Y = 20; }
    Size = @{ Width = 55; Height = 20; }
    Text = "ラベル1"
})
```

単一のオブジェクトを作成できるだけではなく、再帰的に表現できます。しかも`Location`プロパティや`Size`プロパティは`Point`／`Size`型であることがわかっているため、型名を省略可能です。

Comment: ありがとうございます！参考にさせていただきます！